# Org export visible headings only

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm customising my export settings for a particular file using `#+OPTIONS`. I want to be able to set the defaults for `org-export-dispatch` for this particular file too.

In particular I want `Visible only: On` by default (again, for this file only).

The notes that I want to export are not hugely structured, so I don't want to build a sparse tree using particular tags. I just want the currently visible items.

Comment: AFAIK, the `scope`, `body-only` and `visible-only` options cannot be set through options in the file itself. The simplest thing to do is write a function that specializes `org-export-dispatch` to enable the options that you want and use that function for exporting this particular file, instead of using the general dispatcher. Maybe there is a simpler way, but the following is what popped into my head: after you write the specialized function, add a Local variables section to your file and redefine `C-c C-e` to call your specialized dispatcher in that section.

Answer (score -1):

When you're in the buffer, `C-c C-e` brings up the dispatch menu. `C-v` there toggles `Visible only` setting. This seems to do what you want. No special settings are required.

NB I'm using Org 9.5. I don't know if this is a new feature, or no.

Comment: That's the way it's always been. But note that the OP asked for that to be the default setting, so that it would not need to be selected with `C-v` every time. AFAIK, that is not possible with the current dispatcher.